# how to generate a smooth curve in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I am trying to plot a smooth curve with x-axis being time of the day and y-axis is number of login attempts, I have the number of login attempts and the time of the attempts in a Counter which is converted into a panda dataframe, I am using the following code, but it doesn't generate the required graph

```
d = Counter(times)
key = d.keys()
df = pd.DataFrame(d, key)
df.drop(df.columns[1:], inplace=True)
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

This in turn produces the following graph

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9R9kj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visualization of data is quite unintuitive when using libraries like matplotlib, seaborn, bokeh and the like. Thank’s to Jake VanderPlas, there exists [Altair](https://altair-viz.github.io), a declarative libraries that is very straight forward. Just load your not aggregate date data to df.Assuming you have one column of non-aggregated dates you could do:

```
#pip install altair 
import altair as alt

alt.Chart(df).transform_aggregate(
    count='count()',
    groupby=['date']
).mark_line().encode(
    x='date',
    y='count()',\
    tooltip='count:Q'
)
```